# Adding an extra space on the right of my page

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a space on the right of my page to place some extra content like tag cloud, ... like below (marked in red):

[image]

Here is my actual code:

```
<div id="menu">    
    @Html.BuildMenu()
</div>

<div id="content">                
    <div class="outer-gray"> 
        <div class="inner-gray">
            @RenderBody()              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: my outer-gray and inner-gray are used to have a double-border effect.

I'd be so grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figure the CSS property [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) is what you're looking for here. Try something like:

```
#menu { width: 10%; float: left; }
#content { width: 80%; float: left; }
#cloud-tag { width: 10%; float: right; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already defined a width for my menu (let's say 200px). Is it possible to force the width for the cloud-tag to 200px and width:auto for content?

Comment: I tested your solution but my third column (cloud-tag) is located bottom of the content. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/QmP6G/ Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have: 
`<div id="This is my content">` when it should be

```
<div id="content">
```

if you reduce the width of your #content, it should fix it.

Comment: Effectively I do a mistake on the id. Unfortunately it doesn't work: the cloud-tag is still bottom (right) of content. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QmP6G/3/

Comment: If you use fixed width instead of percentage for #content, that will fix it.